# Apply CAShapeLayer to main UIView except UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, cashapelayer

Here is a code which applying mask to the whole UIView:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.bounds];
[maskPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:self.mapCardsButton.center
                                                    radius:self.mapCardsButton.frame.size.height/2.0f
                                                startAngle:0.0f
                                                  endAngle:2.0f*M_PI
                                                 clockwise:NO]];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.fillRule  = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

The problem is that I want to apply the mask above to the whole UIView except one specific UIButton(mapCardsButton) which is also on the same UIView.
Is it possible to do?

UPD: I tried

```
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:maskLayer atIndex:0];
```

instead of

```
self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

but my self.view lost alpha channel and animation of maskLayer doesn't work anymore

Here is a project with code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b94qcwxzoi23kwk/test_04092016.zip?dl=0

Comment: [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

Comment: after I added this code my UIView become to be black without alpha and animation of maskLayer doesn't work anymore.

Comment: so you want to mask full view and only display the full button frame as it's currently displaying

Comment: Expertly What You Are Say ? please See This Image http://imgur.com/6w6mLqm

Comment: Another Image http://imgur.com/xrgokDV

Comment: Rajesh, button has title "BUTTON" which I don't see on you screens

Comment: @Sergio - please take a look at my proposed answer below, I think this achieves what you are looking for. Please let me know if you have other requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try the following? instead of the following stack:

• mask(view) -> button

make the view background color clear, at an additional subview and do the following:

• view -> mask(subView), button

This way you will have the same visual effect, but use the bottom view as a container. In code:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.bounds];
[maskPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:self.mapCardsButton.center
                                                    radius:self.mapCardsButton.frame.size.height/2.0f
                                                startAngle:0.0f
                                                  endAngle:2.0f*M_PI
                                                 clockwise:NO]];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.fillRule  = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

UIView *maskedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];    
maskedView.mask = maskLayer;

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubView:maskedView];
[self.view addSubView:self.mapCardsButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be for the `UIButton` to be a sibling view of the masked view, rather than a subview. I realise that it might make logical sense for the button to be a subview (especially since it looks like your code is probably from a `UIViewController` subclass), so I would create a container `UIView` that holds all the other subviews apart from `mapCardsButton` and apply the mask to this new view.

So say you called the new view `maskedContainerView`, then:

- `self.view` has two subviews: `maskedContainerView` and `mapCardsButton`
- `maskedContainerView` holds all the subviews that `self.view` used to, except `mapCardsButton`
- `maskedContainerView.layer.mask = maskLayer`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried your solution but it still doesn't work. Now it displays mapCardsButton but doesn't make "hole". Here is a project with code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b94qcwxzoi23kwk/test_04092016.zip?dl=0

Comment: Hey. Sorry about the delay. I just looked at your code. I think all that's missing is that the `maskedContainerView` should contain the content that `self.view` used to, i.e. `maskedContainerView` should have its background colour set to the grey/blue background colour that `self.view` is currently set to. Then `self.view` should be completely transparent; `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`.

Comment: stefandouganhyde, nice workaround! I was thinking about that case

Comment: Great! So it looks and functions as you were intending, @Sergio?

Answer (score 0):

[maskedContainerView.layer insertSublayer:maskLayer atIndex:(unsigned)maskedContainerView.layer.sublayers.count];

The importance is view.layer.sublayers.count not 0 at 'atIndex'

[image: success]
Please take it!

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code . I’m not sure is this what you want. [image]

just add the button's UIBezierPath to your maskPath. 
the code like this (Base on your code)

```
const NSInteger kHoleSize = 100;

UIButton *mapCardsButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kHoleSize, kHoleSize )];
[mapCardsButton setTitle:@"BUTTON" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mapCardsButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:mapCardsButton];



UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.bounds];


UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:self.view.center
                                                          radius:kHoleSize/2.0f
                                                      startAngle:0.0f
                                                        endAngle:2.0f*M_PI
                                                       clockwise:NO];

UIBezierPath *buttonPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:mapCardsButton.frame];
[circlePath appendPath:buttonPath];


[maskPath appendPath:circlePath];
[maskPath setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
maskLayer.opacity = 0.9;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];
```